# pandas elimate duplicate rows by creating new columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df:
ID  Name  Exam  Rank_1  Rank_2
1   Rob   Dance     8        7    
1   Rob   Track     7        6    
1   Rob   Skiing    4        9    
2   Sam   Dance     4        9    
2   Sam   Track     6        6
```

Here Exam is a categorical feature and has 3 unique values:[Dance, Track, Skiing]
For every ID, I want to create a single row such that Exam,Rank_1,Rank_2 columns replicate for every exam.

So my new dataframe looks like this:

```
ID Name Dance_Rank_1 Dance_Rank_2 Track_Rank_1 Track_Rank_2 Skiing_Rank_1 Skking_Rank_2
1  Rob       8            7           7             6            4             9
2  Sam       4            9           6             6           NaN           NaN
```

Can anyone help mw with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe) `df.pivot(index=['ID', 'Name'], columns='Exam', values=['Rank_1', 'Rank_2'])`